# Clash between memoir class and footmisc

Tags: memoir, footmisc

how do I get two footmarks separated by a coma with memoir class?

Comment: Your quastein is not clear. Do you mind two successive footnote like `some text\footnote{bla}\footnote{bla bla}`? If this is case, see memoir manual (memman), page 232 ...

Comment: Another [crosspost](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=92517#p92517).

Comment: Title of question and question not comply. But it has, as seems good answer ...

Answer (score 9):

By not doing whatever you are doing to avoid this behaviour:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
abc\footnote{a}\footnote{b}
\end{document}
```

[image]